# How can I have TypeScript infer the value for a constrained generic type when specifying additional types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In TypeScript, I have a function that accepts a generic parameter with constraints:

```js
function f1<U extends string>(param: U): U {
  return param;
}

const a1 = f1('hello');
// a1's type is 'hello' -- Great!
```

Now, I'm trying to make it so you can optionally add another type as part of the return type. However, when I do so, I must supply a default parameter for the U type. This makes it so TypeScript stops inferring the value of U and uses the default type that I supply:

```js
function f2<T = never, U extends string = string>(param: U): U | T {
  return param;
}

const b1 = f2('hello');
// b1's type is 'hello' -- Great!

const b2 = f2<boolean>('hello');
// b2's type is string | boolean -- Terrible: I want the type to be 'hello' | boolean.

const b3 = f2<boolean, 'hello'>('hello');
// b3's type is 'hello' | boolean -- Poor: The type is correct but API is redundant.
```

So my question is, **is there a way I can have TypeScript keep inferring the type from the parameter**? I don't want to supply a default type for U, I always want TypeScript to infer that value. Pseudo-code that shows full API how I'd like:

```js
function f3<T = never, U extends string = infer>(param: U): U | T {
  return param;
}

const c1 = f3('hello');
// c1's type is 'hello' -- Great!

const c2 = f3<boolean>('hello');
// c2's type is 'hello' | boolean -- Great!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. There is a [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349) to add partial inference using the `_` sigil, but it has been inactive for quite a while.

The only solution is to use function currying to get this behavior, although it is not ideal:

```
function f2<T = never>() {
  return function <U extends string = string>(param: U): U | T {
    return param;
  }
}
const b2 = f2<boolean>()('hello');
// b2's type is string | 'hello'
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMATAHgCqILyLAUwDd8AnAPgAoBKRAbwChFET8oQSlRJYFE0BVRPgAeUfGAAmAZ0RSoJGGADmOWfMVLKABwCGJHQFsAXIn5UTggD6IsDJkxZsOiXfoMBuRogC+9XxAQ5RAAjFFVUNGC4OAAbfB0wSioKAHIAC3wYmLgUqk8AenyQlBSZKABPLXxEGBk5BWVEa3TM7JTEeiA)

Comment: It's too bad that PR has stalled, it sure would be a nice feature to have!