# How to have required and optional type parameters in a function and still have working type inference for recod lookup?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, generic-function, keyof

How to make a required type parameter `Y` in a function work together with another type parameter `K` where the latter is only used as a key in a record `R = {a: 'aaa', b: 'bbb'}` lookup and is not supposed to be explicitly provided? The type parameter `K` should be inferred from the value of the first parameter `k` of the funciton `foo`. I want then to use `K` to lookup a type in `R` so that I can use it for the other params of the function.

To allow for only the first type parameter `Y` to be required, the `K` param needs to have a default value. But this default value then breaks the inference of `R[K]` when instead of inferring based on the value of `k` i.e. `R[typeof k]` to `"aaa"` if `k` was `"a"`, it uses the default of `K` i.e. `R[keyof R]` resolving to a union of all types in the record `R` i.e. `"aaa" | "bbb"` disregarding `k`.

Is it possible to have type inferrence for `y: R[keyof K]` where `K` is resolved from the value of `k` without explicitly passing `K`, but still allow for the required type param `Y`?

```js
type R = {
  a: 'aaa',
  b: 'bbb',
}

type Foo = <
  Y,
  K extends keyof R = keyof R,
>(k: K, f: (x: R[K], y: Y) => any) => any

const foo: Foo = (x, y) => null

// With no type params Rec[K] is correctly inferred from K: 'a'
foo('a', (x, y) => null) // x: "aaa"; y: unknown

// When passing the Y type param, Rec[K] ignores the K: 'a'
foo<number>('a', (x, y) => null) // x: "aaa" | "bbb"; y: number

// When passing both Y and K it works
foo<number, 'a'>('a', (x, y) => null) // x: "aaa"; y: number
```

I could only make it work by currying the function so each type parameter belongs to a separate function:

```js
type FooCurried = <K extends keyof R = keyof R>(k: K) =>
  <Y>(f: (x: R[K], y: Y) => any) =>
    any

const fooCurried: FooCurried = x => y => null

fooCurried('a')<number>((x, y) => null) // x: "aaa"; y: number
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a fairly [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490272/how-can-i-have-typescript-infer-the-value-for-a-constrained-generic-type-when-sp?rq=1) where the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62491575/1493220) says that this can only be done by currying the function, as I did in the example.

Comment: Yes, this is only the way to do it